# typeof 2D array is coming out to be String. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, function

- I have something that seems like a 2d-array.
- `typeof` some array will always return an `object`.
- So, why in the following example, the return type is `string`?

```html
<script>

  var x = [typeof x, typeof y][1];
  console.log(typeof x);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `typeof` returns a string, so any `typeof typeof` will also be a string:

```
var x = [typeof x, typeof y][1]; //x is undefined when this is run
console.log(typeof x); //typeof "undefined" == string
```

In the above code, `[typeof x, typeof y]` is equal to `["undefined", "undefined"]`.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```js
var x = [typeof x, typeof y];
console.log(x); //returns ["undefined", "undefined"]
var myVar = x[1];
console.log(myVar); //returns "undefined"
console.log(typeof myVar); //returns string, because "undefined" is a string
```

Answer (score 2):

`[typeof x, typeof y]` evaluates to `["undefined", "undefined"]`. `[typeof x, typeof y][1]` evaluates to `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof <expression>` evaluates to a string, so

```
[typeof x, typeof y]
```

no matter what `x` and `y` are, will resolve to an array like

```
[<someString>, <someString>]
```

Accessing the `[1]`th index of that array will give you one of those strings, so `typeof <someString>` results in `'string'`.